# In ASP.NET MVC5, how do I get the platform and device type of a mobile user request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, mobile, web-applications

Some webapps show a sign-in history, and they can tell that I signed in for example using Android, and with device type 'Samsung GT-I9505'.

I've been looking into the httprequest object in MVC but I cannot seem to find these properties. How can I tell which devices/platforms my users use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent`

For example :

```
string ua = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();
if (ua.Contains("iphone"))
{
    // iPhone
}
else if (ua.Contains("ipad"))
{
    // iPad
}
else if (ua.Contains("GT-I9505"))
{
    // your case
}
```

User-agent list : http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings or http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html

For GT-I9505 : http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings/dv/brand125521/samsung-galaxy-s4

Comment: How would I end up getting something like 'Samsung GT-I9505'? Should I just have a big list of possible devices to check against?

Comment: A list of user-agent : http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings

and for GT-I9505 : http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings/dv/brand125521/samsung-galaxy-s4

Comment: I marked your reply as the answer, even though I should mention that I found the WURFL API which prevents me from having to check for every type with a list of If's. With the WURFL API I can just request the device brand and model name, which is what I was looking for :)